# Javascript 'document.write' generating new HTML+CSS+JS not working on Safari but working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a Ruby on Rails web app. This app allows users to upload videos through a form (using carrierwave as uploader and cloudinary as storage space), which is located into a modal.

Once the user has completed the form and clicked on the 'submit button', I use a javascript code to display an ephemeral page (which is my shared/loading.html.erb view, copied below in the post) with "funfacts" while the video is being uploaded (since the upload can take some time...).

Last, once the upload is completed, the ephemeral page disappears and the user is redirected to the uploaded video (thanks to a traditional 'redirect_to' at the end of a 'create method', in my controller.

- **On Chrome, this mechanism works perfectly** and I have zero warnings or erros message in the browser inspector;
- **On Safari, it does not work and I would like to understand why.** The current situation is that once the button 'submit' has been clicked, the video is being uploaded, the ephemeral loading page is not properly shown (it's either not shown at all or shown but without the javascript), and the redirection works normally once the upload is completed. It's only when I click on the "cross" button in Safari's navbar, in order to stop the uploading process, that the ephemeral loading page works correctly.

Here is my js code, located at the end of my html.erb form:

```html
<!-- My form and modals are above (not shown) -->

<!-- NB: the autocomplete module is in assets/javascript/autocomplete.js -->
<%= content_for :after_js do %>
  <script>
    // Start of js to display the modal
    $('#review_video').change(function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    // End of js to display the modal

    // Start of js to show an ephemeral loading page
    $( "#click-trigger" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log('test 1 - in the click-trigger function');
      var newContent = '<%= j render "shared/loading", layout: false %>';
      document.write(newContent);
    });
    // End of js for loading page

  </script>
<% end %>
```

And, here is below the ephemeral partial (shared/loading.html.erb) that I call in my javascript (let me know if you think of other fun facts ;)).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        background-color: #0098DE;
      }
      .container {
        margin: 100px 15px 20px 15px;
        /*padding: 20px;*/
      }
      .funfacts-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .funfacts-content {
        flex: 0 0 75%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.2em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="funfacts-container">
      <div class="funfacts-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h1>Loading...</h1>
              <h3>Did you know?</h3>
              <span class="loading_element"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function shuffle(a) {
          console.log('test 3 - beginning of shuffle function');
          var j, x, i;
          for (i = a.length; i; i -= 1) {
              j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
              x = a[i - 1];
              a[i - 1] = a[j];
              a[j] = x;
          }
          console.log('test 4 - end of shuffle function');
      }
      var funFacts = ['Gorillas burp when they\'re happy. ^1000','Butterflies taste their food with their feet (and so do our co-founders). ^1000','Studies show that eating spicy food helps you live longer. ^1000','Some turtles breath through their anus. ^1000', 'Ketchup was sold in the 1830\'s as medicine. ^1000'];
      shuffle(funFacts);
      console.log(funFacts);

      console.log('test 2 - in the scrip div of loading.html.erb');
      console.log($('.loading_element'));
      $('.loading_element').typed({
        strings: funFacts,
        loop: true,
        startDelay: 50,
        backSpeed: 15,
        typeSpeed: 30,
        loop: true
      });
      console.log('test 5 - end of .typed script');
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What I did until now to debug:

1. I used some console.logs in different parts of my javascript code (you can see them). I conclude that all my js is working properly but that the HTML+CSS is not displayed correctly.
2. In the inspector and I also saw that I have some warnings reading: 'Unexpected CSS token: :  application-043b483a981042bf2f279f5d418ffcf14d7465d7eae287ea11754a58afff3395.css:4939'. If I click on this error message, it brings me to some bootstrap code that I did not create myself. The error is on the line with 'filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient'  (see below).

```css
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

I understand that the warning is related to the fact that the CSS class is using twice in a row the symbol ":" and that I might use some simple quotes, for example, to fix the warning message. However, I did not create this line of code myself and it seems to be located here : 'line 110, /Users/quentinroquigny/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_dropdowns.scss */', i.e. in the bootstrap gem...
Since it's a warning (not an error), I guess this is not the root of the problem.

Thank for your thoughts guys!

Comment: That is a properties  for IE9 to create a gradient

Comment: The `filter:` is not causing your error.  Safari is simply returning a warning because (as you indicate) the IE-specific formatting is non-standard.  I would recommend re-phrasing your title and contents if possible, to solicit an answer to your actual error rather than the CSS warning.

Comment: It's a warning not an error by Safari because it dosen't like how the line is formatted.  If you double quote that section is should go away.  filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)";

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If those warnings are not breaking the code, I would prefer not to edit the bootstrap code and post my problem with a new title/content as suggested by @Robert C.

Comment: As for the page not rendering try console.log(newContent) This should tell you if you have a problem with rendering the partial.

Comment: @DottedT: thank you. If i console.log(newContent), it renders my partial correctly. In addition, my other console.logs that are in the javascript located in the partial itself are also rendered correctly. **Last information/precision** (I'll edit the post to make it clearer), if I click on the 'cross' button in the browser navbar in order to stop the upload, then my partial and its javascript begin to work correctly...